# Formula for current through shift register

Tags: arduino-uno, current, resistor, shift-register

[image: shift register with leds]

Hi

I am programmer that just started learning electronics and Arduino. I built this simple circuit on Autodesk Circuits earlier. Originally I used 220 ohm resistors. Then when I ran the simulation and turned on more than 4 of the leds the simulator warned that I exceeded the max current for the shift register.

I then upgraded to 560 ohm resistors which solved the problem.

What I would like to know is how can I calculate the current through the shift register for each n-number of leds I turn on? That way I can calculate the right resistor that I need before I burn out my electronics.

Thanks for the help on this.

Comment: Datasheet says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just N×I<sub>L</sub>+I<sub>Q</sub> where N is the number of LEDs, I<sub>L</sub> is the current through each LED and I<sub>Q</sub> is the current the shift register needs to operate (*quiescent* current).

The current through each LED is just (V<sub>IN</sub> - V<sub>LED</sub>) ÷ R, where V<sub>IN</sub> is 5V, V<sub>LED</sub> is the forward voltage drop of the LED, and R is the value of your resistor.

So you can combine it to be a single formula, if all your LEDs are the same and your resistors are the same, to:

I<sub>T</sub> = N × ((V<sub>IN</sub> - V<sub>LED</sub>) ÷ R) + I<sub>Q</sub>

Comment: There's a voltage drop across the shift register, too, but that may not be worth worrying about.  VLED may be most simply measured in operation - or else, calculating based on VLED=0 would somewhat overestimate the current, which isn't really a bad thing to do when comparing against a limit, since it just builds in some margin.  But if the LED were blue with a high forward voltage, then VLED would be very large - if the supply were only 3.3v  it would actually be the majority of the voltage drop.

Comment: Of course, the *correct* thing to do is throw away the poxy shift register and use a proper LED driver with constant current sink... Many are identical in operation from a programming and interfacing perspective, and remove the need for all the resistors completely.

Comment: Thanks. I looked through the data sheet. Can find Iq only Icc and Io for each pin. I also have no idea what the specs are for the leds the simulator does not provide specs. I will just make sure I know the specs before I put together a real circuit.

Comment: Sorry meant I can't find Iq.

Comment: @HeinrichKruger 80µA